# jquery autocomplete not showing dropdown

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have this autocomplete input :

```
<input type="text" id="find_user" class="autocomplete_field" />
```

script :

```
$("#find_user").autocomplete({
        source: "/get_ajax_data.php?type=find_user",
        minLength: 3,
        timeout : 1000,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            window.location.href = "/user_admin.php?action=edit&id=" + ui.item.id

        }
    });
```

When user types in "test" i get the follow result back:

```
[{"id":"26","uname":"test 1","firstname":"Test","lastname":"1","email":"1@mail.com", ............
```

the selection dropdown shows fine

i added an option to show all, put inputting a "*"

```
$(".autocomplete_field").keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '*') {
                $(this).autocomplete('search', "___");
            }
        })
```

result is :

```
[{"id":"1","uname":"admin","firstname":"Ad","lastname":"Min","email":"","lang_iso_code":null,.....................
```

but no selection dropdown is shown.

it works on my local machine, so i thought it could be timeout issues. this is why i added the timeout option (not sure if that correct). Did not help.
I thought it could be data in users other that 'test' user(only two other users)... so i did a search for these two users individually by filling out their names (admin and cron) and data returned fine with selection box showing.

as soon as i try to view all on live site, it does not show the selection dropdown.
although it is only 5 users (admin + cron + three test accounts) 
takes about 440ms to return 2.2kb of data.

i'm using JQ UI 1.11

EDIT :

I just did a test with "___" as the search text and all the users are shown in the dropdown menu. I am assuming the code :

```
$(this).autocomplete('search', "___");
```

does the same thing as when I search for text "___"

in the conlsole i can see the ajax call made, term being set to "___", and the results as above. it's just as if it does not want to show the menu list when i use '*', and only on live server. local works fine.

Comment: I suggest you check out this blog post for jQuery autocomplete UI examples - http://salman-w.blogspot.in/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

after some more testing, and some console outputs in the search and response events, i have come to the conclusion that my code must be causing the autocomplete field to clash with itself.

this code :

```
$(".autocomplete_field").keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == '*') {
            $(this).autocomplete('search', "___");
            console.log(".autocomplete_field search fired");
        }
    })
```

calls the php page and thus returns the data i see in the console.
but during the trace of events firing, i also saw that the original search function also being called :

```
$("#find_user").autocomplete({
    ....
    search: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log("#find_user search fired");
    }
```

it fired in the order above.
thus the second search did not meet the min lenght criteria thus the menu was not show, or cleared, to quick for me to see anything.

with local testing the result came back to quick, I assume, that the first search fired off , got result, and menu was shown, before second search could fire.

My workaround was thus:

```
$(".autocomplete_field").keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == '*') {
                //$(this).autocomplete('search', "___");
                $(this).autocomplete("option", "minLength", 1);
            } else {
                $(this).autocomplete("option", "minLength", 3);
            }
        })
```

With a change in the PHP script that converts the " * " --> "*" which then fits nicely into SQL query ... name LIKE '%*%'. I could have probably made it so that the conversion not necessary with '_' being the list all trigger, but i like the " * " as the trigger.